# JVMSHRC559E Failed to create a directory \"%s\" for the shared class cache while creating server for Websphere liberty profile

Tags: websphere-liberty

I have installed websphere liberty profile and trying to create a server

from Websphere/liberty/bin: server create server1

below errors comes

```
JVMSHRC559E Failed to create a directory "C:\Program Files\IBM\WebSphere\Liberty\usr\servers\.classCache" for the shared class cache
CWWKE0005E: The runtime environment could not be launched.
CWWKE0066E: An exception occurred while creating server server2 at location C:\Program Files\IBM\WebSphere\Liberty\usr\servers\server2.
com.ibm.ws.kernel.boot.LocationException: Unable to create server directory C:\Program Files\IBM\WebSphere\Liberty\usr\servers\server2
        at com.ibm.ws.kernel.boot.BootstrapConfig.verifyServer(BootstrapConfig.java:684)
        at com.ibm.ws.kernel.boot.Launcher.createPlatform(Launcher.java:106)
        at com.ibm.ws.kernel.boot.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:55)
        at com.ibm.ws.kernel.boot.cmdline.EnvCheck.main(EnvCheck.java:52)
                 Java home:  C:\Program Files\IBM\WebSphere\Liberty\java\java_1.7_64\jre
              Install root:  C:/Program Files/IBM/WebSphere/Liberty/
          System libraries:  C:/Program Files/IBM/WebSphere/Liberty/lib/
                 User root:  C:/Program Files/IBM/WebSphere/Liberty/usr/
             Server config:  C:/Program Files/IBM/WebSphere/Liberty/usr/servers/server2/
             Server output:  C:/Program Files/IBM/WebSphere/Liberty/usr/servers/server2/
```

Comment: Do you have write access to the directory? Are you able to create directories/files manually in that directory?

Comment: yes its windows local machine i have tried creating directory manually and its working ...but while creating it asks due to you want to continue and create it as it required admin privileges if i say yes it will create...

Comment: is there any way of passing arguments in command prompt with user

Comment: It sounds like you have a permissions issue in the folder. You could try changing the permissions, or you could open the command prompt as an Administrator (there are various ways, check Google). What kind of arguments do you want to pass?

Answer (score 3):

The problem (as bkail is correct in pointing out), is that the server directory can't be created due to permissions.

Given that you have Liberty installed in the Program Files directory, I would recommend setting the WLP_USER_DIR to move configuration files and servers into a directory you can write to, like C:\Users\\Liberty.

Create a server.env file in the C:\Program Files\IBM\WebSphere\Liberty\etc\ directory, and add the following:

WLP_USER_DIR=C:\Users\\Liberty

(or whatever you choose).

When you run subsequent create/start/stop/etc. operations, it will look for servers and configuration data in that directory instead, which should eliminate the requirement for administrative permissions in order to work with liberty servers.